# How to query in gremlin-javascript case-insensitively

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

Hi I am trying to write a query in Gremlin-Javascript to query AWS Neptune DB.
During the query I want my anchor point to be case insensitive.
I did like this:

```
[errRelatedTicket, relatedTicket] = await to(g.V().hasLabel('Anchor').or(hasId('anchorId'), hasId('ANCHORID'),hasId('anchorid')).in_('SOURCEDATA_HAS_ANCHORPOINT').in_('EVENT_HAS_SOURCEDATA').out('EVENT_HAS_CASE').dedup().toList());
```

But I got an error saying 'hasId not defined', I think there is something wrong with the **'or' step.**
I also tried it in neptune db console.
Actually,  it works using:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Anchor').or(hasId('anchorId'), hasId('ANCHORID')).in('SOURCEDATA_HAS_ANCHORPOINT').in('EVENT_HAS_SOURCEDATA').out('EVENT_HAS_CASE').dedup().toList()
```

did i miss anything?

Comment: I do see the definition of or step in gremlin-javascript lib ``` 
/**
   * Graph traversal or method.
   * @param {...Object} args
   * @returns {GraphTraversal}
   */
  or(...args) {
    this.bytecode.addStep('or', args);
    return this;
  } . 
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import the graph traversal statics, and then use it to start inner traversals:

```
const __ = gremlin.process.statics;

g.V().hasLabel('Anchor')
  .or(__.hasId('anchorId'), __.hasId('ANCHORID'))
  .in('SOURCEDATA_HAS_ANCHORPOINT')
  .in('EVENT_HAS_SOURCEDATA')
  .out('EVENT_HAS_CASE').dedup().toList()
```